# Multi threading a single repetitive task

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a console application that generates(solves) a valid sudoku puzzle from n number of clues but the way I currently have it setup is that my method is called over and over until a valid solution is found. Is this the correct way to implement multi-threading when wanting to run the same function over and over? Or is their another way better way. Appreciate any help!

*GenerateBoard() returns a multidimensional array

```
bool valid = false;

while (valid == false)
            {
            var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GenerateBoard());
            var one = ValidateSolution(task1.Result);
            if (one) { valid = true; } else { Console.WriteLine("Task1 trying again"); }

            var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GenerateBoard());
            var two = ValidateSolution(task2.Result);
            if (two) { valid = true; } else { Console.WriteLine("Task2 trying again"); }

            var task3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GenerateBoard());
            var three = ValidateSolution(task3.Result);
            if (three) { valid = true; } else { Console.WriteLine("Task3 trying again"); }

            var task4 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GenerateBoard());
            var four = ValidateSolution(task4.Result);
            if (four) { valid = true; } else { Console.WriteLine("Task4 trying again"); }}
```

Comment: Every time you start a task, you wait synchronously on it, so you're not actually processing in parallel. Start the four tasks, then use `Task.WhenAny` to monitor their completion

Comment: What happens when more than 1 task is waiting? These tasks take 1-50 ms at most. Is it possible to stop the threads as soon as a task has a valid solution?

Comment: What does `GenerateBoard` do differently each time? Why do you have to call it 4 times in 4 separate tasks?

Comment: It attempts to generate a random valid solution to the Sudoku board (containing n empty spaces) - I was trying to make 4 threads run at the same time so as to reduce the time taken to find a valid solution. Is this a bad way to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can abuse Parallel Linq to search your solutions in parallel:

```
IEnumerable<object> InfiniteEnumerable()
{
    while (true) yield return null;
}

var result = InfiniteEnumerable()
    .AsParallel()
    .Select(_ => GenerateBoard())
    .WithMergeOptions(ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered)
    .AsSequential()
    .First(ValidateSolution);
```

This will automatically use the optimal number of threads for your hardware.

The `.WithMergeOptions(ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered)` and `.AsSequential()` are important to make sure that the processing stops as soon as the first solution is found. As for the `InfiniteEnumerable()`, I don't know if there's a smarter way to tell PLinq to keep processing until the first valid result.

Comment: Note: this assumes that `GenerateBoard` is the expensive part in the computation. If `ValidateSolution` is actually expensive too, you need to compute it before the `AsSequential`

Comment: This works as intended thank you!. How would i add validatesolution before as sequential if it was expensive (although it isn't in my case) just for interest sake.

Comment: @DonioTeixeira One way would be to add a `.Select(b => (isValid: ValidateSolution(b), board: b))` after the first `Select`, and replace the `First(ValidateSolution)` with `First(s => s.isValid)`